# Plotting motion of massive particle around thin shell wormhole

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to plot figure 2(a) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1705.pdf. I'm able to plot the particle's motion from when it first leaves the throat of the wormhole to up until it arrives back to the wormhole. How can I keep the particle going (i.e. extend the graph to include more points) so that I am able to get the exact figure in the paper. Increasing phi seems not to be working. Should I rewrite the equation in terms of tao and then solve it letting tao be anything? Following is the code that I used:

```
rulesDS = {L -> Sqrt[4.5], Energy -> Sqrt[0.949], b -> 1.01};
z[r_] := 2 Sqrt[r - 1] - (2*Sqrt[b - 1] /. rulesDS);
RevolutionPlot3D[{{r, z[r]}, {r, -z[r]}}, {r, 1.01, 
  2 }] 
(*this gives the embedding diagram*)

eq1 = D[r[phi], 
     phi]^2 == (r[
        phi]^4 (Energy^2 - (1 + (L/r[phi])^2) (1 - 1/r[phi])))/L^2;
eq1n = eq1 /. rulesDS;
solDS1N = 
  NDSolve[{eq1n, r[0] == 1.01} /. rulesDS, r, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
        "DAEInitialization" -> {"Collocation", 
          "DefaultStartingValue" -> #}}][[1]] & /@ {1, -1};
solDS1N[[1]] 
(*this solves our differential equation and takes the \
real part of the equation*)

Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{{r, z[r]}, {r, -z[r]}}, {r, 1.01, 1.5}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Magenta, Opacity[0.4], Specularity[White, 10]], 
  MeshStyle -> Blue, PlotPoints -> 30, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False]
 , ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[phi] r[phi], Sin[phi] r[phi], -z[r[phi]]} /. 
   solDS1N[[1]], {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[phi] r[phi], -Sin[phi] r[phi], z[r[phi]]} /. 
   solDS1N[[1]], {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

Comment: See the question and my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270866/trouble-plotting-particle-geodesic-trajectory-on-wormhole-embedding

Comment: I am able to get the plot. I just want to find a way to keep it going on to cover more plot points. How do you think I could do that?

Comment: Why not to use equations from the paper?

Comment: which equation are you referring to? The differential equation I did try solving was equation 3 from the paper. Is there some other equation i should be using as well?

Comment: Exact solution to your equation is given by Equation (9) from the paper.

Comment: How do you think I could code this up? Equation 9 seems hard to code in Mathematica.

Comment: The Jacobi elliptic sine function $sn$ is `JacobiSN` in *Mathematica*, so it should be very easy to code. You can evaluate it to any precision you need.

Comment: I understand the Jacobi Function. I'm only confused about the roots of the polynomial. What should I enter for v1, v2, and v3 in the equation when I'm typing it out in Mathematica.

Comment: Why can’t you find the roots of the polynomial with `Solve`?